# GET ALL Skype Friends using skype APIs With C#

Tags: c#, skype

Is there any way to get all user friend using Skype with C#?
Also how can I get active(online friends).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

first you must add a reference at **SKYPE4COMLib** from the COM reference tab on your project, then make sure that your apllication will be builded as x86 finally try to use this code snippet:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using SKYPE4COMLib;

namespace Example
{
    class SkypeExample
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SkypeClass _skype = new SkypeClass();
            _skype.Attach(7, false);

            IEnumerable<SKYPE4COMLib.User> users = _skype.Friends.OfType<SKYPE4COMLib.User>();

            users
                .Where(u => u.OnlineStatus == TOnlineStatus.olsOnline)
                .OrderBy(u => u.FullName)
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(u => Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is an online friend.", u.FullName));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems with @Ginkas code. I found the below code [here](http://community.skype.com/t5/Desktop-API-former-Public-API/How-to-get-all-Skype-Friends-list-Using-Skype4COM-in-c/td-p/175186) and works like a charm. Also if I remember correctly I instantiate `Skype()` instead of `SkypeClass()`. If you play around you should get only your friends with status active. Hope it helps.

```
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < skype.HardwiredGroups.Count; i++)
            if (skype.HardwiredGroups[i + 1].Type == TGroupType.grpAllFriends)
            {
                for (int j = skype.HardwiredGroups[i + 1].Users.Count; j > 0; j--)
                    Console.WriteLine(skype.HardwiredGroups[i + 1].Users[j].Handle);

                break;
            }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Display Friends Group Error- Exception Source: " + e.Source + " - Exception Message: " + e.Message);
    }
```